# Locate input text by partial Id in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, mocha.js

I need to locate and input text into the text field with the following HTML with Selenium:

```
<input slot="input" class="form-control" id="abc-gib-input-38303-70ft6l7k2g" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="label-abc-gib-input-38303-70ft6l7k2g label-abc-form-38302-42pti7lz8z" aria-describedby="help-text-abc-gib-input-38303-70ft6l7k2g feedback-abc-gib-input-38303-70ft6l7k2g feedback-abc-form-38302-42pti7lz8z help-text-abc-form-38302-42pti7lz8z" type="text" placeholder="" name="login" autocomplete="off">
```

The  problem is each time page reloads the id changes - this part remains the same "abc-gib-input-38303-".
How to select this element?
I tried:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"abc-gib-input"]'))
```

and it does not work.

Comment: What error do you see? How exactly it "not working"?

Comment: The string '//*[contains(@id,"abc-gib-input"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket `)` in your XPath expression.
Instead of

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"abc-gib-input"]'))
```

It should be

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"abc-gib-input")]'))
```

Comment: yes there was a typ, but still I get  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id,"abc-gib-input")]"}

Comment: To help you with this I need to see page you are working on. Preferably the link to it or at least it's HTML, not only the HTML of that single element.

Comment: I found the cause - it is huge. The page is using shadow dom - I need to dig up how to handle it with mocha/selenium.

Comment: You can find several questions about it here. Currently I'm not near the computer so I can't give you links

Comment: Ok so this is a website: https://ingbusiness.pl/gib/login, I need to basically log in. (send keys, and then click the orange button). When I try to execute such function async function getExtShadowRoot() {
    let shadowHost;
   shadowHost = await driver.findElement(By.css("ing-app-gib-main"));
    return await shadowHost.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot")}
} I get error TypeError: shadowHost.executeScript is not a function

Comment: It is not clearly readable in comment. Also, I think now, when you know more details about the issue it would be better to open another, new question for that. Also I'm not so familiar with node.js selenium